# accessing object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code and when I want to access object properties it keep saying undefined. can anyone point out my error.

[image: error msg pic]

```
function readXML()
{
    var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open('GET','index.json',false);
    xml.send();
    var xmlData=xml.responseText;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlData.firstName + " " + xmlData.lastName;


}
```

the json file

```
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:20}
```

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON ? `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: no that's my hole code, is it necessary? because it it works with this code

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =xmlData;

instead of

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    xmlData.firstName + " " + xmlData.lastName;

and it shows the hole opject.

Comment: index.json seems to be JSON file not XML file. wts the content of the file ?

Comment: Http request usually return a string then you have to parse the data yourself.

Comment: Note that JSON is *not* an object, it is a *string* representation of an object. The code in your comment that you say "works" isn't doing what you think: it is just displaying the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered reading about this because of trying to use it, you are missing a simple function called every state change for the request

## Edit, corrected function

Realizing you have `,false)` set for the `async` option, it has been deprecated and is no longer supported, so this function is mandatory.

```
    xml.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200)
      {
        var xmlData = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlData.firstName + " " + xmlData.lastName;
      }
   };
```

This code goes right above the `xml.open()` command.

This function is called on every change of the state of the request, you can also modify it to give an error if you do not receive a `xml.status` of `200`, which means a successfully requested page.

This snippet was edited to fit your function, grabbed from an official website for documenting languages like PHP, JavaScript, JQueryJS, etc.

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

## Edit no. 2

Discovered your json wasn't formatted properly, the values and keys must be encased by `"` or `'`. Here is what it should look like:

`{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}`

from that you can either use `xmlData.firstName` or `xmlData["firstName"]` they both do the same thing.

Next, the `async` parameter has been deprecated, and is completely asynchronous so you have to change your `xml.open()` to this:

`xml.open('GET','index.json');`

Finally for the `onreadystatechange` i modified it to fit your script, the edit is applied above in my previous one.

## ----- Want to see it live? -----

I have uploaded and corrected it to fit your function, it works and is fully function, with no errors processed, here is a link:

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35739016/main.html

Here is the link to the source code:

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35739016/main.txt

And finally, here is what the JSON file should look like:

http://js.x10.bz/helpstack/35739016/index.json

Comment: if it's goes above how will it display data ? btw I tested but it seems that it didn't work
http://puu.sh/nrNg2/a0dd70d57d.png

Comment: It seems I have made an error in converting it to your function i will post the edited completed function in just a sec.

Comment: The above answer should be what you're looking for.